# Cannot shrink a numeric input in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, blazor

I have a simple test program as shown below.
[image]

The razor page

```
<div class="box1">
<input class="numeric" type="number" value="230"/>
<input class="numeric" type="number" value="240"/>
<input class="numeric" type="number" value="250" /><div>
```

The css page

```
.box1{
display:flex;
border:2px solid black;}

.numeric{
text-align:center;
min-width:0px;
max-width:250px;
flex-grow:1;
flex-shrink:1;
flex-basis:150px;}
```

When I strecht the window the inputs are growing.
But when I reduce the window width the inputs are not shrinking
Flex-basis isn't applied neither.

If I replace flex-basis by width it works but I don't undestand why.

```
.numeric{
text-align:center;
min-width:50px;
max-width:250px;
flex-grow:1;
flex-shrink:1;
/*flex-basis:100px;*/
width:100px;}
```

Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: Are you saying that when you reduce the width of the window, the .numeric boxes never shrink width-wise smaller than 150px?

Comment: Yes exactly, but with width:150px it does

Comment: You have `min-width: 50px` and `max-width: 250px`, and you've also set `flex-basis`. What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I would like to allow the input to shrink to a minimum of 50px and grow to a maximum of 250px. Flex-basis is to set the default width isn't it? I tried to remove the line width:100px and it is also working, but the behavior is a bit different probably because of the settings in the Blazor default project and the shrinking of the menu bar.